# Data driven using xml file in java selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, test-automation-framework, data-driven, xml-file

I have already used the data driven approach and executed the test cases using excel file. I mean the data is extracted from excel file. Now I want to extract the data from xml file and execute the test case. Could someone please help me out. Below is the code I have written for reading the excel file and executing the same.

Excel:
[image: Input data structure in Excel spreadsheet]

Code:

```java
    package Test_package;
    
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
    import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
    import org.testng.ITestResult;
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
    import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    
    import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;
    import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentTest;
    import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;
    
    import jxl.Sheet;
    import jxl.Workbook;
    import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;
    
    public class datadriven_coop {
        WebDriver driver;
        ExtentReports extent;
        ExtentTest logger;
        String baseUrl, nodeUrl;
    
        @BeforeTest
        public void startReport(){
    
            extent = new ExtentReports (System.getProperty("user.dir") +"/test-output/STMExtentReport.html", true);
    
            extent
                    .addSystemInfo("Host Name", "SoftwareTestingMaterial")
                    .addSystemInfo("Environment", "Automation Testing")
                    .addSystemInfo("User Name", "Pratiksha Salunkhe");
    
    
                    extent.loadConfig(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/extent-config.xml"));
        }
        @BeforeMethod
          public void beforeMethod() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
    
    
    
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Chrome\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
          }
    
        @DataProvider(name="Cooplogin")
        public Object[][] loginData() throws BiffException, IOException {
            Object[][] arrayObject = getExcelData("C:\\Standalone\\ABC.xls","Sheet2");
            return arrayObject;
        }
    
    
        public String[][] getExcelData(String fileName, String sheetName) throws BiffException, IOException {
            String[][] arrayExcelData = null;
            try
            {
                FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(fileName);
                Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fs);
                Sheet sh = wb.getSheet(sheetName);
    
                int totalNoOfCols = sh.getColumns();
                int totalNoOfRows = sh.getRows();
                System.out.println(totalNoOfCols);
                System.out.println(totalNoOfRows);
    
                arrayExcelData = new String[totalNoOfRows-1][totalNoOfCols];
    
                for (int i= 1 ; i<totalNoOfRows; i++) {
    
                    for (int j=0; j<totalNoOfCols; j++) {
                        arrayExcelData[i-1][j] = sh.getCell(j, i).getContents();
                    }
    
                }
    
    
            }
    
    
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BiffException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
                return arrayExcelData;
    
        }
    
        @Test(dataProvider="Cooplogin")
        public void Coop_produkt(String Username,String password,String Category,String Subcategory,String Category1,String Subcategory1) throws InterruptedException {
    
            logger = extent.startTest("Coop_produkt");
         driver.get("https://www.coopathome.ch/de/");
    
               Thread.sleep(5000);
    
    
               //fruits
               driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='nav']/ul/li[1]/a/span")).click();
               Thread.sleep(2000);
               driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='subnav--item-m_0001']/li[1]/ul[1]/li[1]/a")).click();
               Thread.sleep(2000);
               JavascriptExecutor jse8= (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
               jse8.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,400)", "");
               driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/ul/li[1]/div/div/div[3]/button")).click();
               Thread.sleep(2000);
               driver.findElement(By.id("j_username")).sendKeys(Username);
               driver.findElement(By.id("j_password")).sendKeys(password);
               driver.findElement(By.id("loginOverlaySubmitLoginFormButton")).click();
               Thread.sleep(2000);
    
               driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/ul/li[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/button[2]")).click();
    
               //Shampoo & Salad
               Thread.sleep(4000);
              driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[contains(text(),'" +Category+ "')]")).click();
    
               Thread.sleep(4000);
               driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[contains(text(),'" +Subcategory+ "')]")).click();
               Thread.sleep(4000);
               driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sortOptions']")).click();
               Select dropdown1=new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("sort")));
               dropdown1.selectByVisibleText("Preis (absteigend)");
               JavascriptExecutor jse7= (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
               jse7.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,400)", "");
               driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/ul/li[1]/div/div/div[3]/button")).click();
               Thread.sleep(4000);
               driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/ul/li[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/button[2]")).click();
    
               //Drinks & Beer
               Thread.sleep(4000);
               driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[contains(text(),'" +Category1+ "')]")).click();
               Thread.sleep(4000);
               driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[contains(text(),'" +Subcategory1+ "')]")).click();
               Thread.sleep(4000);
               driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sortOptions']")).click();
               Select dropdown2=new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("sort")));
               dropdown2.selectByVisibleText("Preis (absteigend)");
               JavascriptExecutor jse6= (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
               jse6.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,500)", "");
               driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/ul/li[1]/div/div/div[3]/button")).click();;
               Thread.sleep(4000);
               driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/ul/li[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/button[2]")).click();
               Thread.sleep(4000);
    
               //add to cart
               driver.findElement(By.id("miniCartProceedToCheckoutButton")).click();
               Thread.sleep(4000);
               driver.findElement(By.id("miniCartProceedToCheckoutButton")).click();
               Thread.sleep(4000);
    
               //Date for delivery
               driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='heimlieferung']/div[4]/dl/dd[3]/a")).click();
               driver.findElement(By.id("chooseDeliveryDate_continue_button")).click();
               WebElement t=driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/dd"));
               if (t.getText().equals("120.40"))
               {
                      System.out.println("Gesamtkosten ist korrekt");
                      logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Validierung erfolgreich : Gesamtkosten ist korrekt");
    
                      } 
               else {
               System.out.println("Gesamtkosten ist nicht korrekt, Erwarteten Gesamtkosten ist "+ t.getText()); 
               }
               JavascriptExecutor jse18= (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
                jse18.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,500)", "");
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[5]/form/div[2]/p/a")).click();
    
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span[2]/a[1]")).click();
    
    
                //Alert alert=driver.switchTo().alert();
                Thread.sleep(4000);
                if(driver.findElement(By.id("removeAllItemsBtn")).isDisplayed())
                {
                    driver.findElement(By.id("removeAllItemsBtn")).click();
                }
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/nav[2]/div/ul/li[7]/a")).click();
    System.out.println("Jetzt ist den Warenkorb leer und Sie können neues Produkt wieder hinzufügen");
    logger.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Jetzt ist den Warenkorb leer und Sie koennen neues Produkt wieder hinzufuegen");
                logger.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Coop_produkt Testfall ist erfolgreicht");
             }
    
    
        @AfterMethod
        public void getResult(ITestResult result){
    
            if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE){
                logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Test Case Failed is "+result.getName());
                logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Test Case Failed is "+result.getThrowable());
            }else if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP){
                logger.log(LogStatus.SKIP, "Test Case Skipped is "+result.getName());
            }
    
            extent.endTest(logger);
        }
    
    
        @AfterTest
        public void endReport(){
    
                    extent.flush();
    
    }
    }
```

Comment: I believe you're specifically looking at how to have xml be your data provider or paremeters when using the **testing** test framework. [Here is a random link I googled that might help with this.](https://www.guru99.com/parameterization-using-xml-and-dataproviders-selenium.html) And perhaps [this is a little cleaner example](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/testng-parameters-data-provider/)

Comment: Your question is unclear and lacks essential details necessary to provide a meaningful answer, please read the following and update your question https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask